# Closures over __class__

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, python-internals

I was recently stepping through the CPython source code, specifically viewing the [symbol table entry](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/symtable.h) for a class during compilation.

I bumped into the following entry for the [`typedef struct _symtable_entry`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/symtable.h#l55) structure:

```
[-- other entries --]
unsigned ste_needs_class_closure : 1; /* for class scopes, true if a
                                         closure over __class__
                                         should be created */
[-- other entries --]
```

I really can't seem to understand it and can't find an example of python code that actually sets `ste_needs_class_closure == 1`. Among other failed attempts, I have tried the following:

```
class foo:
    y = 30
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 50
    def foobar(self):
        def barfoo():
            print(self.x)
            print(y)
        return barfoo
```

But even though it executes, the value of `ste_needs_class_closure` during execution is `0` and not `1` as I hoped it would be.

The function which actually alters this value is [`drop_class_free`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/symtable.c#l575) which doesn't help much. Unfortunately, it also doesn't have any comments complimenting it.

It is actually used in [`analyze_block`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/symtable.c#l700) with a comment of:

```
/* Check if any local variables must be converted to cell variables */
```

Which I can understand as a concept but cannot find an example where it happens.

I've tried searching [the changelog for Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#cpython-implementation-changes), the version in which this member first appeared but no references to it were found.

So, can anyone explain what is meant by **closure over __class__** that is, when do local variables of a class get converted to cell variables?  Ideally, an example that actually makes this behaviour visible during execution would be wonderfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Github’s blame view for that line of code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/master/Include/symtable.h#L55) shows us that it was added in [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/04b4e5be3ad443417f8a0f26602e499051560f66), which references [Issue #12370](http://bugs.python.org/12370): Prevent class bodies from interfering with the `__class__` closure.

From the bug report, an example of the type of problem this was trying to fix is:

> In Python 3 the following code prints `False` because the use of
>   `super()` has caused the `__class__` descriptor to be omitted from the
>   class namespace. Remove the use of `super` and it prints `True`.
>
> ```
> class X(object):
>     def __init__(self):
>         super().__init__()
>
>     @property
>     def __class__(self):
>         return int
>
> print (isinstance(X(), int))
> ```

(Note that this code uses the [new super()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/).)

Regarding the functionality of the patch, also from the bug report:

> The patch basically causes the following class statement:
>
> ```
> class C(A, B, metaclass=meta):
>     def f(self):
>         return __class__
> ```
>
> To be compiled approximately like this:
>
> ```
> def _outer_C(*__args__, **__kw__):
>     class _inner_C(*__args__, **__kw__):
>         def f(self):
>             return __class__
>     __class__ = _inner_C
>     return _inner_C 
> C = _outer_C(A, B, metaclass=meta)
> ```

… although some later discussion suggests that the handling of `__args__` and `__kw__` may have changed in the final patch.